# can't run a make file of a C program

Tags: c, make

I have a small  a program that should start a 2nd Thread. the problem is that, when try to make an executable file  of this program using make. I get :

```
 engine@ubuntu:~/Desktop/Lecture$ make thread
 cc     thread.c   -o thread
 thread.c: In function ‘main’:
  thread.c:10:2: error: unknown type name ‘pthread’  .............
```

here is my code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <errno.h>

void *func(void*);

int main(){

pthread tid;
if (pthread_create(&tid,NULL,fun,NULL)!= 0 ){
    printf("error by _ pthread \n");
}
printf ( "thread output1 \n");
sleep(1);
return EXIT_SUCCESS;
  }  

 void *fun(void* data){
printf("thread output2 \n")
  }
```

I don't think that program is wrong, it maybe the way I'm running the make command ?

any Idea why do I get this. 
thanks in advance for your help

Comment: this isn't related to ubuntu. i've flagged your question; it'll probably get moved to Stack Overflow.

Comment: You need to compile it as `gcc -pthread -o thread thread.c`. Check your makefile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you forget to link a dynamic library?

> cc     thread.c   -o thread -lpthread

Further errors:

> - type of pthread is pthread_t
> - you misspelled fun and func
> - no semicolon in function after printf

Comment: thanks benjamin for help , it work but to be honest I don't understand what 'a dynamic library'  mean I'll google it

Answer (score 0):

According to the manual page for `pthread_create` and some sample code around the internet, the first parameter is a pointer to `pthread_t`, not `pthread`. Try that:

```
pthread_t tid;
```